# Fazer update no schema de um usuário

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Olá! Recentemente no discord eu fiz um sistema de clans, usando o mongodb atlas, para aprender como ele funciona. O problema é que ele cria o schema no atlas certinho, mas dá o update no schema do usuário.

Aqui estão os dois Schemas:

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true },
    tag: { type: String, required: false },
    clan: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    clan_name: { type: String, default: 'The member has no clan.' },
    coins: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    wood: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    rock: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    gold: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

const Clan = new mongoose.Schema({
    _name: { type: String, required: true },
    all: { type: Array, default: [] },
    owner: { type: String, required: true },
    co_owners: { type: Array, default: 'The clan doesn\'t have co-owners.' },
    members: { type: Array, default: 'The clan doesn\'t have members.' },
    bankLevel: { Type: Number, default: 0 },
    bankGold: { Type: Number, default: 0 },
    bankRock: { Type: Number, default: 0 },
    bankWood: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    members_counter: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

Este é o código do comando para criar o clan:

```
const { Command } = require('discord-akairo');
const { RedEmbed, GreenEmbed } = require("../../Helpers/EmbedHelper");
const Database = require("../../Database");

class CreateClanCommand extends Command {
    constructor() {
        super('createClan', {
            aliases: ['create-clan', 'criarClan', 'criar-clan'],
            category: 'RPG',
            args: [{ id: 'name' }]
        });
    }
    async exec(message, args) {

            await Database.Users.findOne({ '_id': message.author.id }, function (error, document) {

            if (document) {
                if (document.clan === true) {
                    return new RedEmbed('já tens um clan');

                } else {
                    if (document.gold < 500) return new RedEmbed("n tens ouro", message);
                    if (!args.name) return new RedEmbed("põe um nome", message);
                    if (args.name.length > 15) return new RedEmbed("nome com + de 15 caractéres", message);
                    if (args.name.length < 5) return new RedEmbed("nome com - de caractéres", message);

                    let newClan = new Database.Clans({
                        _name: args.name,
                        all: [message.author.id],
                        owner: message.author.id,
                        co_owners: 'The clan doesn\'t have co-owners.',
                        members: 'The clan doesn\'t have members.',
                        bankLevel: 1,
                        bankGold: 0,
                        bankRock: 0,
                        bankWood: 0,
                        members_counter: 1
                    });
                    newClan.save();
                    new RedEmbed('criaste um clan', message)

                    let updateUser = new Database.Users({
                        _id: message.author.id,
                        tag: message.author.tag,
                        clan: true,
                        clan_name: 'The member has no clan.',
                        coins: 0,
                        wood: 0,
                        rock: 0,
                        gold: 0,
                    });
                    updateUser.save();
                }
            } else {
                return new RedEmbed('n tens conta', message);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = CreateClanCommand;
```

E o erro fala sobre uma key duplicado, e eu não faço ideia como o resolver:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, eu encontrei no stacks uma matéria que pode te ajudar, ela esta muito bem explicada

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

caso tenha alguma duvida perinente a ela pode comentar.

Espero ter ajudado